# Ruby Client cannot read from C Server: socket.gets hangs

Tags: c, ruby, sockets, networking, client-server

I have a server in C and a client in Ruby. My ruby client is able to send a string successfully to my C server, but it is not able to receive any input from it.

More specifically, the 'gets' method in my 'recv' method in client.rb is hanging. Starting my client.rb program looks like this:

```
[user]$ ruby client.rb
## CLIENT STARTED ##
user: myuser       //user enters username and password here
password: mypass   // It hangs after this line, so I press ctrl-C

^Cclient.rb:27:in `gets': Interrupt     //This is the output after pressing ctrl-C
from client.rb:27:in `verifyUser'
from client.rb:40:in `main'
from client.rb:48
```

while the output of my server would be:

```
## SERVER STARTED ##
[Wed Aug 13 12:19:43 2014]  21 bytes  0 myuser mypass
write succeed
request processed
```

According to my output, writing to the client succeeded. But my ruby client is hanging when calling socket.gets in the recv method. I have also tried using socket.read and that also hangs. I only need to get the first byte, or just one line of input from my server.

Why can't my client receive input from my server?

The list of things that are supposed to happen is:

- server started
- client started and user enters username and password
- server receives username and password
- server sends string to client
- client receives string from server
- client does some operations depending on the string

**client.rb**

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1'
$port = 29008

def send(msg)
  socket = TCPSocket.new($ip, $port)
  socket.write(msg)
  socket.close
end

def recv
  socket = TCPSocket.new($ip, $port)
  data = socket.gets
  socket.close
  data
end

def verifyUser(user, pw)
  send("0 #{user.chomp!} #{pw.chomp!}")
  recv =~ /^0/
end


def main

  puts "## CLIENT STARTED ##"
  print "user: "
  user = gets
  print "password: "
  pw = gets

  if verifyUser(user, pw) then
    puts "user verified"
  else
    puts "wrong user or password"
  end

end

main
```

**server.c**

```
/* PROCESS REQUEST */
void processRequest(char *input, int cfd) {

  int option = 0;
  char *ch = "0";

  if (option == 0) {

     if (send(cfd, ch, strlen(ch), 0) < 0) {
        puts ("write error");
     } else {
        puts ("write succeed");
     }

  } else {
     puts("option is not valid");
  }
}



int main() {

  int sfd, cfd;
  int optval = 1;
  char buffer[2000];
  char input[2000];
  int len;
  int idx = 0;
  time_t currTime;
  char *time_str;


  struct sockaddr_in saddr, caddr;


  sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


  saddr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* Set address family to IPv4 Internet */
  saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* Any internet address */
  saddr.sin_port = htons(29008); /* Set server port to 29008 */

 setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval);

  bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));


  listen(sfd, 1);

  printf("## SERVER STARTED ##\n");

  while (1) {



        if ((cfd = accept(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
                puts("client connection failed");
        }

        /* get time of message */
        currTime = time(NULL);
        time_str = asctime(localtime(&currTime));
        time_str[strlen(time_str) - 1] = '\0';


        /* ensure that all everything is received from client */
        while ((len = recv(cfd, buffer, 2000, 0)) > 0) {

                buffer[len] = '\0';

                if (idx == 0) {
                   strcpy(input, buffer);
                } else {
                   strcat(input, buffer);
                }

                /* log message */
                printf ("[%s]  %d bytes  %s\n", time_str, len, input);

                idx++;
        }

        if (len < 0) {
                printf("recieve failed\n");
                return 1;
        }

        processRequest(input,cfd);
        puts("request processed");


        close(cfd);

        idx = 0;
        input[0] = '\0';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

- I have revised my server.c code to reflect on what I have now. I changed the strlen(input) parameter that was in the send method into strlen(ch). The problem still remains.
- I've tested my server via telnet, and the results are the same. I am able to write to my server, but not read from it. This leads me to believe that there is nothing wrong with my Ruby client. This has to be a problem with the way my server is sending data.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ruby: send() and recv() should both use the same socket, not each use a different, new socket.
2. Ruby: gets() depends on a newline for knowing when input is done.
3. C: similarly to #2, your recv() is waiting for 2000 bytes to end the loop, not a newline or anything.

Ruby code:

```
def send(socket, msg)
  socket.puts(msg) # puts() adds a newline for the server.
  socket.flush     # Probably not necessary.
end

def recv(socket)
  # gets() doesn't end until receives a newline.
  socket.gets
end

def verifyUser(user, pw)
  response = ''
  
  # Use 1 socket for both send/recv.
  # Can use open() with a block to auto-close
  #   at the end of the block.
  TCPSocket.open($ip, $port) do |socket|
    send(socket,"0 #{user.chomp!} #{pw.chomp!}")
    response = recv(socket)
  end
  
  response =~ /^0/
end
```

C code:

```
void processRequest(char *input, int cfd) {
  int option = 0;
  char *ch = "0\n"; // Newline!

  //...
}

//...

        /* ensure that all everything is received from client */
        while ((len = recv(cfd, buffer, 2000, 0)) > 0) {

                buffer[len] = '\0';
                
                if (idx == 0) {
                   strcpy(input, buffer);
                } else {
                   strcat(input, buffer);
                }

                /* log message */
                printf ("[%s]  %d bytes  %s\n", time_str, len, input);

                idx++;
                
                // Note that this is just a simple version.
                // You probably want to store a substring into input.
                // Then save the rest of the substring in the buffer.
                // Include "stdbool.h" if don't want to use an int.
                int has_newline = 0;
                
                for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                  if(buffer[i] == '\n') {
                    printf("Breaking out of loop.\n");
                    has_newline = 1;
                    break;
                  }
                }
                
                if(has_newline == 1) {
                  break;
                }
        }

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer:

1) in the ruby code you're not using the same socket to write and read from the server.  Create the socket in verifyUser and pass it into send/recv - this way you keep the connection to the server.

```
def send(s, msg)
  print("sending: '" + msg + "'\n")
  s.write(msg)
  s.flush
end

def recv(s)
  print("in recv");
  data = s.recv(1024)
  print("got data: " + data);
  data   
end

def verifyUser(user, pw)
  socket = TCPSocket.new($ip, $port)
  send(socket,"0 #{user.chomp!} #{pw.chomp!}\0")
  resp = recv(socket) 
  socket.close
  resp =~ /^0/
end
```

2) in the c server -  the len = recv while loop - do you really need a while loop?   The server reads the command and the loops again. The only reason it worked before is because you closed the socket and the recv then got and error, popped out of the loop and processed the request.  If you put the processRequest right under the printf with the timestamp, you'll see that the server does indeed send a response.  And if you sort out the ruby client side socket stuff, you'll actually get that response.

Comment: Sorry I had edited the processRequest method and forgot to take the extra parameter out. I've updated my server.c code based on what you said. It compiles. My server.c code is reaching the "write succeed" and "request processed" print statements so I believe the server side is able to send the string successfully. The client side still hangs at "socket.gets"

Comment: And yes, the server side is getting the connection in the first place. I posted above what the server's output is when the client connects with it. Essentially I can get the client to send a string successfully to the server, but I cannot get it to read from the server.

Comment: Note that I revised my comment above.